# How can I add custom action button in backoffice of SAP Hybris 1905?

Tags: action, sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

Below is what I did, but it is not working for me.

1. Create definition.xml at this path:
   `<NAME_OF_EXTENSION>/backoffice/resources/widgets/actions/<NAME_OF_ACTION>`
2. Create an Action class
3. Add the Action Button to the Widget (Adding entry into `<NAME_OF_EXTENSION>-backoffice-config.xml`)

However, I still cannot see the button in the BackOffice page.

Comment: Are you trying to add the action to a custom widget?

Comment: Yes
in console am getting below warning
WARN [hybrisHTTP38] [DefaultActionRenderer] Illegal configuration! Action class ‘com.stroetmannbackoffice.actions.ProductExclusiveGroupsAutomation’ requires ‘java.lang.String’ as input, yet configured to be used in context of ‘java.util.LinkedHashSet’
ProductExclusiveGroupsAutomation is my action class

Comment: Can you post your action class, the configuration from point 3 and the connection made with `<widget-connection>` ?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following post that I wrote on how to do this in detail:
[Adding Custom Action Button in Backoffice of SAP Hybris](https://waqasaslam.me/2019/02/01/adding-custom-action-button-in-backoffice-of-sap-hybris/)